# Russian Porter stemming in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, stemming

Does someone have an example of Russian Porter stemming in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't get it. Why the downvotes? The question seems legitimate to me.

Comment: Maybe you can build off of this: https://github.com/cwolves/stem

Answer (score 4):

~15 seconds on Google:

http://urim.googlecode.com/svn/jsSnowball/stemmer/src/ext/RussianStemmer.js

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it before, but this [might be](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/js.txt) what you need?